# How to Update database with $json_encode() PHP Function

Tags: php, ajax, json, jquery-ui

I like update my database with jquery,php and Ajax using json_encode and Ajax Post,but I don't understand how to use a array $json_encode for update the database with for each loop.
¿So how I can Update my database with $json_encode?

This is my response in console when click save order button :

```json
{
    "success": true,
    "parent_id": [
        "0,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,0,0,0"
    ],
    "order_page": [
        "3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,0,1,2"
    ],
    "id_page": [
        "17,8,9,2,3,4,5,6,7,11,10,1,16,14,15"
    ]
}
```

This is my post ajax php event saveorder.php

```php
<?php 
    header('Content-type: text/javascript');
    $json = array('success'=>false,
                  'parent_id' =>array($_POST['parent_id']),
                  'order_page' => array($_POST['order_page']),
                  'id_page'=>array($_POST['id_page'])
    );
if(isset($_POST['parent_id'],$_POST['order_page'],$_POST['id_page'])){
    $json = array('success'=>true,
                  'parent_id' =>array($_POST['parent_id']),
                  'order_page' => array($_POST['order_page']),
                  'id_page'=>array($_POST['id_page'])
            );
    echo json_encode($json);    
    $con = $this->connect();
    $Ordersaved=json_decode($json); 
    foreach($Ordersaved as $key){
        mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE pages SET parent_id='$parent_id' Order_Page=$order_page ID_Page=$id_page WHERE Section_ID=0 " );
    }

}
elseif(is_null($_POST['parent_id'],$_POST['order_page'],$_POST['id_page'])){
    echo "Las variables son nulas";
}
function connect(){
    return mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","root","db");
}
?>
```

And this is my db:

```html
CREATE TABLE `pages` (
  `ID_Page` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `TitlePage` varchar(255)   NOT NULL,
  `SectionPage` varchar(255)   NOT NULL,
  `CategoryPage` varchar(255)   NOT NULL,
  `NamePage` varchar(255)   NOT NULL,
  `BodyPage` varchar(9000)   NOT NULL,
  `DescriptionPage` varchar(255)   NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Section_ID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Category_ID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Order_Page` int(11) DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=18 DEFAULT ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to explain, I think you can spot the difference :

```
$json = array('success'=>false,
                  'parent_id' => $_POST['parent_id'],
                  'order_page' => $_POST['order_page'],
                  'id_page'=>$_POST['id_page']
    );
if(isset($_POST['parent_id'],$_POST['order_page'],$_POST['id_page'])){
    $json = array('success'=>true,
                  'parent_id' => $_POST['parent_id'],
                  'order_page' => $_POST['order_page'],
                  'id_page'=> $_POST['id_page'])
            );
    echo json_encode($json);    
    $con = $this->connect();
    // HERE
    mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE pages SET parent_id=".$json['parent_id'].", Order_Page=".$json['order_page'].", ID_Page=".$json['id_page']." WHERE Section_ID=0 " )

    // $Ordersaved=json_decode($json); 
    //foreach($Ordersaved as $key){
       // mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE pages SET parent_id='$parent_id' Order_Page=$order_page ID_Page=$id_page WHERE Section_ID=0 " );
    //}
```

Comment: That's not save the data in mysqli .But thanks for your atention.

Comment: For save data in the database ,the code doesn't works

Comment: print the query before  `mysqli_query` and run it on phpmyadmin